# My Random Number Generator is Not Outputting Correctly

Tags: java, random, numbers, generator

I have tried to get this to print out 2 and 2 on separate lines. The separate lines part I've got down but for some reason the numbers this thing is outputting is 2 then 3. This is for an assignment for one of my chapters and getting a group together for help is challenging because of my work schedule. Can anyone help me to understand what is going on here? NOTE: seedVal starts at 4.

> type two statements using nextInt() to print two random integers
>   between 0 and 9. End with a newline. Ex:
>
> 5
>
> 7
>
> Note: For this activity, using one statement may yield different
>   output (due to the compiler calling nextInt() in a different order).
>   Use two statements for this activity.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceRoll {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Random randGen = new Random();
        int seedVal = 0;
        randGen.setSeed(seedVal);

        System.out.println(randGen.nextInt(seedVal));

        System.out.println(randGen.nextInt(seedVal));

        return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would it print out 2 and 2 on separate lines?

Comment: This throws `IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive` on the first call to `nextInt`.

Comment: ["int nextInt(int n) Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))

Comment: You are trying to give it a seed when it expects the upper range value. From that same link: "Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if n is not positive"

Comment: Nope, seedVal does not start at 4: `int seedVal = 0;`

Comment: doesn't setSeed() expects a long int as a parameter? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed-long-

Comment: This particular assignment is in ZyBooks. It's an online textbook and this is one of the challenges. I have to make this block of code print out those two particular numbers. The webpage automatically changes the seedVal as to test the code under different circumstances.

Comment: @StarksAreBack I'm pretty sure the `int` gets converted to a `long`.

Comment: The code needs to print out `2` twice? That is not random. What is the assignment asking you to do? Can you paste the problem statement here?

Comment: ype two statements using nextInt() to print two random integers between 0 and 9. End with a newline. Ex: 
5
7
Note: For this activity, using one statement may yield different output (due to the compiler calling nextInt() in a different order). Use two statements for this activity.

Comment: Can you add that to the body of your question? Click the (small) "edit" link underneath the tags.

Comment: Ok, so you don't even need to set the seed. Look again at the link I quoted above (don't even need to follow the link; the text is right there in my comment). You want a random number between 0 and 9; `nextInt(int n)` takes one argument as the upper bound of the range.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing I do is producing the results the textbook wants. I will have to take this one up with the author and my instructor. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`new Random()` is indeed a pseudo-random returning the same values in the same order for the same seed every time you use it.
The lower bound is zero, so you need to add 1 to the result because you cannot throw 0 with dice. The upper bound is 6 (which returns a random between 0 and 5, but we're adding 1 to compensate for the 0 lower bound).
To print the same result twice, you need to store it in a variable and print it twice of course.
Luckily, the first 'random' returned for the combination of seed 6 and bound 6 is 1. Add 1 and you have your 2 ;-)

Something like this:

```
public class DiceRoll {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Random randGen = new Random();
        int seedVal = 6;
        randGen.setSeed(seedVal);

       int diceValue = randGen.nextInt(6) + 1;
       System.out.println(diceValue);

       System.out.println(diceValue);

       return;
   }
}
```

Comment: `seedVal` is not a good variable name for an upper bound. Seed <> Upper Bound.

Comment: Again, it is not good to confuse the seed with the upper bound. The two are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

randGen.nextInt(10) indicates the number of possible values starting from 0, so the largest is 9. Since the prompt wants 2 statements you need to put the print out twice.

System.out.println(randGen.nextInt(10));
System.out.println(randGen.nextInt(10));